# Grails integration test for domain class: No signature of method exception

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-domain-class

I try to write integration test for domain classes in my project. However each time I run the test I got some errors.

My code is below:

```
class ProductIntegrationTest extends GroovyTestCase {

    void testSave() {
        def product = new Product(name: "phone")
        product.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
        assert.....
    }
}
```

After I run the test, the exception is:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Product.save() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: save(), save(boolean), save(java.util.Map), wait(), last(), any()
```

However, if I put a `@TestFor(Product)` annotation for the domain class, the error has gone. I found in the document for integration test we can't put `@TestFor` annotation because it is only for unit test.

Anyone get some idea?

Comment: Did you put this class in `tests\integration` folder?

Comment: I strongly suggest to use the command grails create-integration-test to create an integration test. You would not see this issue if the test class is on appropriate directory as mentioned by @Sergio.

Comment: To Sérgio, yes all the integration tests are put in the folder test/integration folder and I used the command line to generate the integration tests.

Comment: Your strongly recommendation is what I did but still have this problem.

Comment: Well then I do not see a reason why it should fail. Which version of Grails are you using? Moreover, if you are using Grails 2.x then the command line integration Test creation should yield to `ProductIntegrationTests` instead of `ProductIntegrationTest` if supplied arg is `ProductIntegration`. Can you share your domain class as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Late answer, but I ran into this today.  One possible issue is that a different test within your `test/integration` directory is extending `GrailsUnitTestCase`.  When executing `grails test-app integration`, this gives problems for subsequent tests, but not the test that is improperly extending `GrailsUnitTestCase`.  Moving these classes to `test/unit` or changing the extension to `GroovyTestCase` will fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. I found that I had forgot to setup the data source for the test environment. In DataSource.groovy make sure you have setup a datasource for each datasource setup for development.